# Group associated with a non-Galois field extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-groups

Here is an example of what I have in mind. Consider the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$. An automorphism of this extension would have the form $\sqrt[3]{2}\mapsto \zeta\sqrt[3]{2}$ with $\zeta$ a third root of unity, and since there are no non-trivial third roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}$, the extension has no non-trivial automorphisms. But in some sense, I would want to say that the automorphisms of the extension are identified with third roots of unity. So let me make an ad-hoc definition $\mathrm{Gal}'(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}):=\mu_3$, where $\mu_3$ is the finite algebraic group of third roots of unity. I am wondering if there is a reasonable way to generalize this definition.

Optimistically, for an arbitrary finite (separable?) extension $L/K$, one might hope for a finite algebraic group $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)$ defined over $K$, which acts (algebraically) on the extension $L/K$. Without having a precise definition in mind, I might expect:

- the dimension of the coordinate ring of $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)$ is equal to $[L:K]$,
- $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)(K)\simeq\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)$,
- there is a Galois correspondence in which algebraic subgroups defined over $K$ correspond to intermediate fields, and
- $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)$ is isomorphic to the split algebraic group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ if $L/K$ is Galois.

My first thought was that maybe $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)$ should represent the functor taking a $K$-algebra $R$ to the group of $R$-algebra automorphisms of $L\otimes_K R$. But this group is too big, since its coordinate ring has dimension $[L:K]!$.

My question is: is this something that's been studied? Is there a reasonable way to define $\mathrm{Gal}'(L/K)$ in general?

Comment: Not quite what you want, but let me remark that Grothendieck's Galois theory tell us that finite, separable extensions $L/K$ are classified by $\operatorname{Hom}(L,K^{sep})$ as a $\mathrm{Gal}(K^{sep}/K)$-set and this set has cardinality $[L\colon K]$ (here, $K^{sep}$ is a chosen separable closure of $K$). This Hom-set is not a group, but it still acts on $L/K$ in a sense.